# What is the default replication factor in Gemfire XD?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, gemfire

I am creating some tables, which is showing replication factor as 1. Is it the default replication factor or it is due to fact that GemFire XD is installed in pseudo distribution environment?

I am trying this query to verify that by default table is replicated or not.
And it is showing replicated

> select tablename, datapolicy from sys.systables where tableschemaname='APP';

Answer (score 1):

In gemfireXD, if you don't specify partition, the table will be replicated to all the servers in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The default GF replication factor is 0. This number is the number of redundant copies GF maintains in its cluster. To verify I created a sample hdfs table and queried the table properties. I got this:

```
create table HDFS_TABLE (col1 int, primary key(col1)) partition by primary key hdfsstore(store);

select tablename, PARTITIONATTRS from sys.systables;
TABLENAME                             |PARTITIONATTRS
...
HDFS_TABLE                            |redundantCopies=0,...
...
```

Can you provide more details? Are you talking about HDFS replication factor?

Comment: No by default it is replicated. Try this query in Gemfire XD terminal :                                                  select tablename, datapolicy from sys.systables where
tableschemaname='APP'; Under data policy it will show either replicate or partition